# How to change the color of a custom renderer text to the title color in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, colors, renderer

I have the following chart:

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('chartcontainer', {
  chart: {
    polar: true,
    type: 'column'
  }, 
  [other code]
       }, function (chart) {
         chart.renderer.text(textLine, 40, 80).css({'red'}).add();
       });
```

The renderer.text() function gives me customText which can be easily modified. However, this graph is used in a somewhat more complex situation where the context will determine the color of the text (so it is not fixed to 'red'). I need to give it the color of the title. The title colors are set through the options somewhere else.

It all works fine but I do not seem to be able to get that color value AND assign it properly to the text color value, something like this:

```
chart.customText.style.color = chart.title.style.color;
```

How must this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the color by: `chart.title.styles.color`. Example:

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    ...
}, function(chart) {
    chart.renderer.text('Some text', 40, 80).css({
        color: chart.title.styles.color
    }).add();
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/10u2nLay/

Comment: Thank you very much. I have been very close but I must have made some typos that I could not get it working...
And reviewing my entry: I used 'style' iso 'styles'.
Sorry for that :( but thanks for replying!!)